# How to force Delphi to use D8.bat instead of dx.bat to compile Java 1.8 bytecode into DEX bytecode

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, dx, android-d8

Today I faced a problem. My project needs to use some libraries (*.jar) that use Java 1.8 features. I see more and more libraries use now Java 1.8 features (like webRTC, exoplayer, etc.). In this way, we must do **desugaring**.

> Desugaring allows you to use these features on older devices by replacing new bytecodes and language APIs with older ones during the build process

With `d8.bat` (replacement of `dx.bat`), desugaring is turned on by default. So you can now use most of the latest language changes while targeting older devices.

When we compile a project, in the background Delphi does this:

> dx.bat --dex --output="C:\Dev\output\libwebrtc-dexed.jar" "C:\Dev\lib\libwebrtc.jar"

And this fails with a library that contains Java 1.8 features.

So Delphi must do this instead:

> d8.bat --lib C:\SDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-28\android.jar --output="C:\Dev\output\libwebrtc-dexed.jar" "C:\Dev\lib\libwebrtc.jar"

Any idea how I can tell Delphi to use `d8.bat` instead of `dx.bat`?

Comment: Perhaps you could modify dx.bat so that it does what d8 does?

Comment: @DaveNottage or even to just have it call d8.bat instead

Comment: yes it is in one of my idea, but i would like to know if their is not another solution that will avoid me to "spoil" my android SDK

Comment: How would it "spoil" the SDK?

Comment: @DaveNottage: because now dx.bat will be not anymore the original dx.bat, so product like android studio will not work anymore. but yes this solution is possible!

Comment: @DaveNottage finally i try, just replacing Dx by D8 didn't work :( it's much more higher job :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution modifying the "CodeGear.Common.Targets" file (Delphi's bin folder), creating an alternative command to be used only for dex generation using the d8.bat instead of the dx.bat:

1) Close the IDE

2) Edit the "CodeGear.Common.Targets", localize the DxCmd definition, and add this two new lines, creating a new command for d8.bat:

```
<JavaD8Path>@(JavaAaptPath->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')d8.bat</JavaD8Path>
<D8Cmd>PATH $(JDKPath)\bin;$(PATH) %26 "$(JavaD8Path)" --output=</D8Cmd>
```

3) Now localize the target used to generate the dex files and replace the **DxCmd** by the new **D8Cmd**

```
  <!-- Generate a "dexed" version of the customized jar files if they doesn´t exists -->
  <Target Name="BuildPredexedJar" DependsOnTargets="GetProjectJars">
    <Exec Condition="( '@(_JarsLocations)'!='' And !Exists('%(_JarsLocations.PredexedJar)') )"
        Command='$(D8Cmd)"%(_JarsLocations.PredexedJar)" %22%(_JarsLocations.FullPath)%22'/>
  </Target>
```

4) Now the dex generation will use the d8.bat compiler, where "desugaring" is turned on by default.